# Iterator of something like str

Tags: string, rust

As I am poking at Rust, I was trying to write a Rust function that can take a look at anything iterable of strings.

My initial attempt was

```rust
fn example_1(iter: impl Iterator<Item=&str>);
fn example_2(iter: impl Iterator<Item=&String>);
// ...
```

that requires two functions for different cases.

I also tried combining cases above into one, and what I got is:

```rust
fn example_3<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized + Deref<str>>(iter: impl Iterator<Item=&'a T>);
```

that can accept both `Iterator<Item=&String>` and `Iterator<Item=&str>`, but not `Iterator<String>` (because last one requires one more borrow in the function body). Also, it looks way more complex than it probably should.

I of course can implement this using custom `trait`, maybe involving `AsRef`, but I think I might be missing a better and clearer way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an excellent use case for [`std::borrow::Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html). `Borrow` is for types that can reasonably be borrowed into a similar-looking but not literally identical type (`String` borrows as `&str`, `PathBuf` borrows as `&Path`, etc.)

```
fn example<'a, I, T>(iter: I)
where I : Iterator<Item=T>,
      T : Borrow<str> {
  for x in iter {
    let my_string: &str = x.borrow();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Note that this will work for `String` and `&str`, but not, as you suggest in your example, `&String`. If you end up with an iterator of `&String`, then you might question how you got there (`&String` is useless for the same reason `&Vec<T>` is; it's objectively worse than `&str` in every way). But if you for some reason wind up with an iterator of `&String`, you can get to `&str` with

```
my_iter.map(|x| &**x));
```

One `*` gets rid of the `&`, one `*` derefs the `String` to `str`, then the `&` borrows the `str`. Congratulations! You're a [two-star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) now.

Or, more simply (thanks, user4815162342),

```
my_iter.map(|x| x.as_str())
```

Comment: Great answer, but I'd always prefer something like `.map(|s| s.as_str())` to the two-star (or even one-star) syntax.

Comment: And there's where my lack of experience as a Rust dev shows. That's much simpler, thank you.

Comment: I actually tried to use `Borrow`, but failed to reach the desired result for some reason. Thank you! I'll probably use this or settle with `map(|x| x.as_str())` (which I've discovered too). I was just thinking are there better ways, and your answer checks this out.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this more easily using two generics, one to represent the string type and one for the iterator. While you can do this with `Deref`, the `AsRef` trait would be better here since there can be multiple `AsRef` implementations for a given type, and it's a little bit more generic. Here's an example that will work with `&str`, `&String`, `String`, and so on.

```
fn example<S: AsRef<str>, T: Iterator<Item=S>>(iter: T) {
    for string in iter {
        println!("String: {}", string.as_ref());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's beautiful! Thank you, but for the simplicity of code I'll probably use another answer.